# Where can I find prices of tickets sold by airlines?

Tags: data-request, transportation, prices

I am looking for data from as many airlines as possible throughout the whole world.

Answer (score 2):

The [US Bureau of Transportation Statistics](http://www.rita.dot.gov/bts/) provides various stats and datasets for historical airline ticket prices.

- [General overview, datasets and statistics](http://www.rita.dot.gov/bts/data_and_statistics/index.html)
- [Airfare data](http://www.rita.dot.gov/bts/airfares)

From the Route Fares page:

- [Route fares](http://www.dot.gov/policy/aviation-policy/domestic-airline-fares-consumer-report)

If you go through the PDF report (2012 to Q1 2014), you can find the corresponding raw data (CSV/Excel) for each table.

[image]